# How to display a pop up that is like a dialog message from an span element

Tags: html, css, dialog

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="total">
  <span id="pledged-money" class="money">
    <p>${{ total.amount }}
      <span class="btn btn-xs btn-info question-mark"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-placement="top"
            title="Hello there">
        !
      </span>
    </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

with the following scss:

```
#pledged-money {
  p {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
    margin-left: 10px ;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    width: 9%;
  }
}
```

As a result I have the following:
[image]

So far everything is okay, but what I need is to display a dialog when clicking on this span element like this:[image]

I have not too much experience with HTML and CSS and I am currently stuck with this. How can I display this element that has a close button and the dialog pointing to the span element.

Answer (score 2):

If you use bootstrap, it would be very easy to implement the popup message.

Use bootstrap **popover**, here is the link for reference https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp